# mongodb with scala maven project

Tags: scala

I am stuck on an issue. I have created a scala maven project where I am trying to communicate with mongo. My project is getting build successfuly and I do not get any error when I execute my project, but still no data is getting inserted in my mongodb.

If I insert data manually through mongo-cli then my code can read it but it is not even inserting a single record.
Could you please help me in finding where I am making mistakes.
My mongo version is 3.2.10

App.scala

```
package com.assignment.scala

import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Aggregates._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Projections._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Sorts._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Updates._
import org.mongodb.scala.model._

/**
 * @author ${user.name}
 */
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Calling insertDoc==")
    insertDoc()
  }

  def insertDoc() = {
    val mongoClient = MongoClient()
    val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("assignment")
    val collection = database.getCollection("links")

   println("collection find : " + collection.find())
   collection.find().subscribe(
  (user: Document) => println("document------------"+user.toJson()),    
  (error: Throwable) => println(s"Query failed: ${error.getMessage}"),
  () => println("Done"))

    collection.drop()

    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/home/impadmin/ServiceSource/ml-latest-small/links.csv")
    var firstLine = List[String]();
    var docList = List[Document]();
    for ((line,count) <- bufferedSource.getLines.zipWithIndex) {
      val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      if (firstLine.size <= 0 && cols.length > 0) {
        firstLine = cols.toList;
      } else {
        var doc: Document = Document("_id" -> count)
        for ((a, b) <- firstLine zip cols) {
          doc ++= Document(a -> b)
        }
        docList = docList :+ doc
        collection.insertOne(doc)
      }
    }

    val doc3 = Document("name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
      "count" -> 1, "info" -> Document("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))

   collection.insertOne(doc)
   collection.find().subscribe((doc1: Document) => println(doc1.toJson()),
   (e: Throwable) => println(s"There was an error: $e"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create `doc3` but never use it?

Comment: I tried to insert doc3 as well but it is not getting inserted. I think mongo is supporting read only operations only but not inserting or dropping collection.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using subscribe:

```
val insertObservable1: Observable[Completed] =              collection.insertMany(docList);
            val latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1)

            insertObservable1.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {

              override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
                println("Error1")
                e.printStackTrace()
              }

              override def onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription): Unit = {
                subscription.request(java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE)
                println("inserting1-------------")
              }

              override def onComplete(): Unit = {
                println("Completed1")
                latch1.countDown()
              }

              override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = {
                println("Next1-----------")
              }

            })
            latch1.await()
          }
        })
```